# margin top doesn't work on a simple div

Tags: html, css

I made a simple div called test below my navagation but wanted to put the div lower using margin-top,
That doesnt seem to work.

the margin-top is in test{}

What is the problem?

Here is the the css is used.

```
#menu {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 7px 7px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.44);
    -moz-box-shadow:    7px 7px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.44);
    box-shadow:         7px 7px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.44);
    margin: auto;
    width: 700px;
    height: 60px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 3px 2px 3px #333333;
    border-radius: 8px;
    background-image: url(navbar.jpg);
}

#test {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 7px 7px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.44);
    -moz-box-shadow:    7px 7px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.44);
    box-shadow:         7px 7px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.44);
    margin-top: 80px;       /* doesn't work! */
    margin: auto;
    border-radius: 8px;
    width: 700px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: gray;
}

#menu ul {
    height: auto;
    padding: 8px 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    margin-top: 10%;
}

#menu li { 
    display: inline; 
    padding: 20px; 
}

#menu a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
}

#menu a:hover {
    color: #F90;
}
```

Comment: `margin: auto;` override `margin-top: 80px;` value. Please try to merge them as: `margin: 80px auto 0;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dear Follow these steps:

1)

```
 body
{
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}
```

2)

```
#test {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 7px 7px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.44);
    -moz-box-shadow:    7px 7px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.44);
    box-shadow:         7px 7px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.44);
    margin-top: 80px;       /* doesn't work! */
    border-radius: 8px;
    width: 700px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: gray;
}
```